# Saving API Information Into a Database - Using Django and Fetch API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, put

I'm new to APIs with Javascript and Django. I have a project where an API is called in Javascript, and it gets weather information for a specific location (the user types the location into a form first). Currently it does not save the weather info to the database.

If the user clicks 'add to favorites' for the location, only then I want to save that info to the database.

My question is, would I use a PUT request for this? Also, would I need a totally different fetch request for this, or would I be able to take the one I already have, and just get that data somehow. I'm assuming to save it to the database I would probably need a separate fetch request using PUT, because I only want it to save when the user clicks a button.

Here is what I have for the API to get the weather data (this works correctly but this does not save to the database yet).

```
function hi() {
    function temperature(input) {
    const myKey = "private";
    const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
    q=${input}&lang=en&appid=${myKey}&units=metric`;

    return fetch(api).then(function(response){
      let data = response.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    })
  }
```

Any guidance is appreciated, as I mentioned, I'm very new to this and trying to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a js expert but about your Http methods:

You should use `PUT` method when you are updating all of the fields of your object or you have a form that user can update anything he/she wants.

When you are updating only one field for example changing its status when you click on a button, use `PATCH` instead.

You can still do it with `PUT` and everything will work fine but it's better to use `PATCH` instead of `PUT` on partial updates, it's more maintainable and readable.

So use `PUT` on updates and `PATCH` on **partial updates**.

When user clicks on add to favorites you need to call your API endpoint after the button is clicked.